# Autodesk forge viewer, aggregatedView,React & Ts unable to initialize

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to implement a simple React component that initializes the forge viewer using the AggregatedView and loads a couple of models, but I am getting the following error:
[image]

This is my component:AggregatedView.tsx

```
import { initializeViewer } from "./Aggregated-helper"
declare var Autodesk: any

export interface ForgeViewerProps {
  urn: string
  accessToken: string
}

const models = [
  { urn: 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLktmSE5VSkFSUklxdE53RnZUM2o2MUE_dmVyc2lvbj0x' },
  { urn: 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLllhbk0wUHZxVGFLVnJJbnJKSG9OaFE_dmVyc2lvbj0z' }
];

const AggregatedViewer = (props: ForgeViewerProps) => {
  const { accessToken } = props
  const viewer3DRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accessToken || !viewer3DRef || !Autodesk) {
      console.log("error")
      return
    }
    initializeViewer(viewer3DRef, models, accessToken)
  }, [accessToken])

  return(
    <>
      <div
        ref={viewer3DRef}
        className="ForgeViewer"
        style={{ height: "100%" }}
      ></div>
    </>
  ) 

  
}

export default AggregatedViewer
```

My helper: Aggregated-helper.ts

```
declare var Autodesk: any
let viewer
export const initializeViewer = async (refElement: any, models: any, accessToken: string) => {

    const options = {
        env: "AutodeskProduction",
        accessToken: accessToken,
        api:'derivativeV2'
    }

    const options3d = {
        viewerConfig: {
            disableBimWalkInfoIcon: true
        }
    };

    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, async function () {
        const view = new Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView();
        await view.init(refElement, options3d)
       viewer=view.viewer
        const tasks: any = [];
        models.forEach((md: { urn: string; }) => tasks.push(loadManifest(md.urn)));
        Promise.all(tasks)
            .then(docs => Promise.resolve(docs.map(doc => {
                const bubbles = doc.getRoot().search({ type: 'geometry', role: '3d' });
                const bubble = bubbles[0];
                if (!bubble) return null;
                return bubble;
            })))
            .then(bubbles => view.setNodes(bubbles))
    })

    function loadManifest(documentId: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (doc: any) => {
                doc.downloadAecModelData(() => resolve(doc));
            };
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, reject);
        });
    }

}
```

The error seems to be triggered in:

```
await view.init(refElement, options3d)
```

of the helper.
Can someone help me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `view.init` method expects an HTML element as its first argument but it looks like you're passing in a "React ref". Try the following instead:

```js
await view.init(refElement.current, options3d)
```